# Meaning of the word Samkaram

Tags: shiva

What is the meaning of the word Samkaram?

For example i know that samkaram stumah mean bowing at the Feet of Lord Shiva.

Comment: It seems your question belongs here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123261/sanskrit-language  
Please do ask it there as many users of Hinduism.SE will use and benefit from Sanskrit.SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the forthcoming Sanskrit.SE ( https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123261/sanskrit-language )

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what "S" is used at the start.

If it's the dental S then the word [Sankara (सङ्कर)  means](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=sankara&direct=au&anz=100) inter-mixture, cross-breed, polluted due to mixture etc.
An usage of this word is "Varna-Sankara" which means inter mixture of castes which causes pollution in the caste system.

But, if it's the palatal Sh, then the word is Shankara (शङ्कर) and it means "one who creates peace", auspicious etc. This Shankara is one name of Lord Shiva as found in the Vedas.

> Namah shambhave cha mayobhave cha |
>
> Salutation to the source of peace, and to the source of delight.
>
> Namah **shankara**ya cha mayaskaraya cha |
>
> Salutation to the **one who creates peace (Sham)** and to the creator
>   of delight.
>
> *Mantras from Taitiriya Samhita*